# Python : Get many list from a list

Tags: python, list, slice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

Hi,

I would like to split a list in many list of a length of x elements, like:

`a = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`

and get :

`b = (
  (1,2),
  (3,4),
  (5,)
)`

if the length is set to 2 or :

`b = (
  (1,2,3),
  (4,5)
)`

if the length is equal to 3 ...

Is there a nice way to write this ? Otherwise I think the best way is to write it using an iterator ...

Comment: First of all, () is a tuple, not a list. In case you don't know, a tuple is essentially an immutable list.

Comment: Basically the same as [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python), except that you may have to add a `tuple` conversion.

Comment: Yeah, that question has a more comprehensive list (;-)) of answers including one identical to mine except in name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [itertools module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#module-itertools). Read it, learn it, love it.

Specifically, from the recipes section:

```
import itertools

def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
  "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
  args = [iter(iterable)] * n
  return itertools.izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

Which gives:

```
>>> tuple(grouper(3, (1,2,3,4,5)))
((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, None))
```

which isn't quite what you want...you don't want the `None` in there...so. a quick fix:

```
>>> tuple(tuple(n for n in t if n) for t in grouper(3, (1,2,3,4,5)))
((1, 2, 3), (4, 5))
```

If you don't like typing the list comprehension every time, we can move its logic into the function:

```
def my_grouper(n, iterable):
  "my_grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG') --> ABC DEF G"
  args = [iter(iterable)] * n
  return tuple(tuple(n for n in t if n)
       for t in itertools.izip_longest(*args))
```

Which gives:

```
>>> tuple(my_grouper(3, (1,2,3,4,5)))
((1, 2, 3), (4, 5))
```

Done.

Comment: hope the source list doesn't contain embedded `None`'s, that'd be icky...

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: true. You could always use another value as a sentinel, and/or make the sentinel another argument to `my_grouper`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I'd do it. Iteration, but in a list comprehension. Note the type gets mixed; this may or may not be desired.

```
def sublist(seq, length):
    return [seq[i:i + length] for i in xrange(0, len(seq), length)]
```

Usage:

```
>>> sublist((1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 1)
[(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,)]

>>> sublist([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2)
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5]]

>>> sublist('12345', 3)
['123', '45']

>>> sublist([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 73)
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]

>>> sublist((1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in sublist
ValueError: xrange() arg 3 must not be zero
```

Of course, you can easily make it produce a `tuple` too if you want - replace the list comprehension `[...]` with `tuple(...)`. You could also replace `seq[i:i + length]` with `tuple(seq[i:i + length])` or `list(seq[i:i + length])` to make it return a fixed type.

Comment: My results with your code do not match: `>>> sublist((1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 1)
[(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,)]
>>> sublist((1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 2)
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5,)]
` They are correct, but use tuples, and your notation for tuples in the first case is wrong. Did you cut and paste these results from a shell session?

Comment: @hughdbrown: Sorry, normally I do but for once I cheated, knowing what it would do, and made a mistake in the tuple notation. Naturally it should be (1,) etc. rather than (1). Corrected now.

Answer (score 2):

From the python docs on the itertools module:

```
from itertools import izip_longest
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

Example:

```
>>> tuple(grouper(3, (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)))
((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, None, None))
```