# Collect every pair of elements from a list into tuples in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of small integers, say:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I wish to collect the sequential pairs and return a new list containing tuples created from those pairs, i.e.:

```
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

I know there must be a really simple way to do this, but can't quite work it out.

Thanks

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, please use the [homework] tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pairs from single list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628290/pairs-from-single-list) and many others.

Comment: @S.Lott, why could it be a homework? Does it look like from your experience?

Comment: Not homework, personal interest

Comment: @S.Lott it's for carrying out aside processing on pre-existing data passed from a different program.

Comment: @TartanLlama: "pre-existing data passed from a different program"?  Perhaps you should ask your **real** question.  It sounds like the other program may have a design problem or the input parser may have  a small design problem.  Creating a flat list like this and reformatting it into pairs is less than ideal.  There may be a way to avoid all of this.

Comment: @S.Lott: Obviously I've got changes to make there, this was more out of interest because I realized that I didn't know how to carry out this task.

Comment: n-duplicated: just in a quick search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501636, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170295, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287

Comment: I'm not sure what "impractical" even means in this situation. Software challenges are often the result of data being in impractical shapes. Consider an old way of organizing data that must change due to new business requirements. A judgement like "impractical" is full of assumptions and speculation based in smoke.

Comment: @jaydel: Not really.  The input can be always be built into pairs as it's being read.  Reading as a flat list and restructuring the list can always be avoided.  It isn't "speculation".  It's a matter of changing the software design to assemble the desired data structure straight away.  If it can be assembled in two steps, it can be refactored so the assembly happens in one step.

Comment: @S.Lott: what I'm saying is that at one point having that input as a list, and also still needing it as that list is a situation that might have been made necessary due to business logic and requirements. In a new release an instance where it's required to be in the new format might now exist and have the list already in hand. All I'm saying is that the practicalness or impracticalness is defined by business requirements and the behavior of the program. My opinion is that you don't have enough information to make that call. I don't mean this as an attack. You just don't have the full context.

Comment: @jaydel:  If it can be assembled in two steps, it can be refactored so the assembly happens in one step.  It's not a matter of "business requirements".  It's a matter of design.  Any inefficient two-step process can be refactored to a more efficient one-step process.  I understand that the flat list may have some value, but the comment "pre-existing data passed from a different program" seems to indicate that the flat list had no other purpose.  Yes, I could be wrong.  Fixing the design, however, could be more efficient than the answers to this question.

Comment: I'll buy that. I think the thing that originally tripped me up was the hard assertion that it was impractical. I mentally added 'seems' or even 'is probably' before it and felt much better.

Comment: @jaydel: Given the comment ("pre-existing data passed from a different program") it sure seems like the design is utterly impractical.  There is still a real possibility that the comment is incorrect or incomplete.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Well there is one very easy, but somewhat fragile way, zip it with sliced versions of itself.

```
zipped = zip(mylist[0::2], mylist[1::2])
```

In case you didn't know, the last slice parameter is the "step". So we select every second item in the list starting from zero (1, 3, 5). Then we do the same but starting from one (2, 4, 6) and make tuples out of them with `zip`.

Comment: An odd number of elements may have surprising results.  Also, a zero-length list will behave badly.

Comment: the solution to fragility can be this small tweak (if you don't mind having empty string when elements are odd) `if len(mylist)%2 !=0:
 mylist.append('') ;
 zip(mylist[0::2], mylist[1::2])`

Comment: `zipped = itertools.zip_longest(mylist[0::2], mylist[1::2])` to pad odd length lists, default `fillvalue=None`

Answer (score 11):

Apart from the above answers, you also need to know the simplest of way too (if you hadn't known already)

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
o = [(l[i],l[i+1]) for i in range(0,len(l),2)]
```

Comment: I'd completely forgot about the optional step parameter to range

Comment: why do you substract 2 from length? it's wrong.

Comment: This will silently drop the last element of an odd-length list.  Is that appropriate?   Or should it raise some kind of exception?

Comment: @S.Lott: this sort of question typically deal only with even-length lists.

Comment: This will not work for sure, list index out of range exception is thrown.

Comment: thanks for your short & clear & simple answer

Comment: This is working for me, the accepted answer doesn't, but in my case the list is always even.

Answer (score 7):

Straight from the Python documentation of the [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) module:

```
from itertools import tee, izip

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for pair in pairwise(l):
    print pair
```

Comment: +1. Aye, there arrived a more robust way :D

Comment: This doesn't quite give what the OP requested - it prints `(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6)` instead of `(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)`

Comment: The right function is `grouper`, right below this one in the itertools recipes ;)