# How to turn a string with unquoted keys into a dict in Python

Tags: python

I have a string

```
"{a:'b', c:'d',e:''}"
```

Please not that the keys to the dictionary entries are unquoted, so a simple `eval("{a:'b', c:'d',e:''}")` as suggested in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/converting-a-string-to-dictionary) does not work.

What would be the most convenient way to convert this string to a dictionary?

```
{'a':'b', 'c':'d', 'e':''}
```

Comment: What is the source of those of such a string?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I'm guessing it's a Javascript object literal (_not_ JSON, which requires the property names to be quoted).

Comment: None of the answers here currently work in the general case.  Consider a tokenizer-based approach, as described by user2357112 answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52900880/674039).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the complexity of what you're parsing, this could work:

```
s = "{a:'b', c:'d',e:''}"
d = dict([
    (x.split(':')[0].strip(), x.split(':')[1].strip("' "))
    for x in s.strip("{}").split(',')
])
```

Answer (score 7):

If this is from a **trusted source** (do not use this for general user input, as [eval is not secure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661084/security-of-pythons-eval-on-untrusted-strings); but then again, if you're getting input from a potentially malicious user you should use JSON format and the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) instead), you can use `eval` with a trick.

```
source = """{e: '', a: 'b', c: 'd'}"""

class identdict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return key

d = eval(source, identdict())
print(d)
```

prints

```
{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': ''}
```

How this works is that we create a new dictionary subclass `identdict` that defines the magic method `__missing__`. This method is called for lookups on keys that are missing from the dictionary. In this case, we just return the key, so the dictionary maps keys to themselves. Then the `source` is `eval`uated using an `identdict` instance as the `globals` argument. `eval` will look up the values of variables from the `globals` mapping; as it is an `identdict`, the value of each variable accessed is conveniently now the name of the variable.

Works for even more complex strings as values, and anything that is proper Python literal syntax.

Comment: Nice. Although my content is alphanumeric only, good to learn something new. As I already accepted the other answer, I only can upvote for you. Appreciate.

Comment: @Harrison it is always possible for you to change the accepted answer

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Great little hack! But how exactly does this work? I'm not quite understanding how this gets past the `NameError`, shouldn't that be raised before the dictionary even deals with a a missing value? And how does it return a string? I added `print(type(key))` to the` __missing__` method, and it prints `<class int>` if I do something like `id[1]`, where `id` is an `identdict`, and if I do something like `id[x]` where x is not defined, I get a `NameError` and the `__missing__` method is never called! Clearly, I'm not understanding exactly what the `eval` built-in is doing.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga no, the global variables in python are stored in a module-wise dictionary; additionally mapping of local variables can be provided to `eval`. Normally `eval` defaults to those mappings which are returned by calls to `globals()` and `locals()`; now instead we use a `identdict` instance.

Comment: This is a really underrated answer. Would be a really great example to quickly map the call hierarchy here.

Comment: Hacky.  Fails for `"{e: '', a: 'b', if: 'd'}"`.

Answer (score 1):

Manual parsing is error-prone and hard to make general, and `eval`-based approaches fail when the keys are Python keywords. The currently accepted answer breaks if values contain spaces, commas, or colons, and the `eval` answer can't handle keys like `if` or `for`.

Instead, we can [tokenize](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html) the input as a series of Python tokens and replace `NAME` tokens with `STRING` tokens, then untokenize to build a valid dict literal. From there, we can just call [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

```
import ast
import io
import tokenize

def parse(x):
    tokens = tokenize.generate_tokens(io.StringIO(x).readline)
    modified_tokens = (
        (tokenize.STRING, repr(token.string)) if token.type == tokenize.NAME else token[:2]
        for token in tokens)

    fixed_input = tokenize.untokenize(modified_tokens)

    return ast.literal_eval(fixed_input)
```

Then `parse("{a:'b', c:'d',e:''}") == {'a':'b', 'c':'d', 'e':''}`, and no problems occur with keywords as keys or special characters in the values:

```
>>> parse('{a: 2, if: 3}')
{'a': 2, 'if': 3}
>>> parse("{c: ' : , '}")
{'c': ' : , '}
```

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING** This approach will not work as desired if you have a key mapping to an empty string in the middle of your "dictionary." I'll not delete this answer because I think this approach might still be salvageable.

This might be a little more general than Will's answer, although, it is still going to depend on the exact structure of what you are parsing. If your key, value pairs will consist of alphanumeric words, you should be fine, though.

```
In [3]: import re

In [4]: import itertools

In [5]: my_string = "{a:'b', c:'d',e:''}"

In [6]: temp = re.findall(r"\w", my_string)

In [7]: temp = itertools.zip_longest(temp[0::2], temp[1::2], fillvalue = "")

In [8]: dict(temp)
Out[8]: {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': ''}
```

If you want to know what is happening with the zip function, see these questions:

[Collect every pair of elements from a list into tuples in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647050/collect-every-pair-of-elements-from-a-list-into-tuples-in-python)

I used `itertools.zip_longest` so you can use a fill value, inspired by:

[Pairs from single list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628290/pairs-from-single-list)

Comment: Hmm, on second thought, this will not work as desired if you have a key mapping to an empty string in the middle of your "dictionary." Well, it might still be useful.

Comment: seems like someone downvoted everyone. I voted it back for you.

Comment: This is very much dependent on the exact contents of the string.

Comment: Right, I've acknowledged this deficiency in the first comment. Should I edit the answer to include a warning?

Answer (score -1):

```
import re
str="{a:'b', c:'d',e:''}"
dict([i.replace("'","").split(":") for i in re.findall(r"(\w+\:'.*?')",str)])
```