# Converting key=value pairs back into Python dicts

Tags: python, string, dictionary, parsing

There's a logfile with text in the form of space-separated `key=value` pairs, and each line was originally serialized from data in a Python dict, something like:

```
' '.join([f'{k}={v!r}' for k,v in d.items()])
```

The keys are always just strings. The values could be anything that [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) can successfully parse, no more no less.

**How to process this logfile and turn the lines back into Python dicts?** Example:

```
>>> to_dict("key='hello world'")
{'key': 'hello world'}

>>> to_dict("k1='v1' k2='v2'")
{'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2'}

>>> to_dict("s='1234' n=1234")
{'s': '1234', 'n': 1234}

>>> to_dict("""k4='k5="hello"' k5={'k6': ['potato']}""")
{'k4': 'k5="hello"', 'k5': {'k6': ['potato']}}
```

Here is some extra context about the data:

- Keys are [valid names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers)
- Input lines are well-formed (e.g. no dangling brackets)
- The data is trusted (unsafe functions such as  [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval), [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec), `yaml.load` are OK to use)
- Order is not important. Performance is not important. Correctness is important.

***Edit:***  As requested in the comments, here is an MCVE and an example code that didn't work correctly

```
>>> def to_dict(s):
...     s = s.replace(' ', ', ')
...     return eval(f"dict({s})")
... 
... 
>>> to_dict("k1='v1' k2='v2'")
{'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2'}  # OK
>>> to_dict("s='1234' n=1234")
{'s': '1234', 'n': 1234}  # OK
>>> to_dict("key='hello world'")
{'key': 'hello, world'}  # Incorrect, the value was corrupted
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem individually. A good way to show this effort is to include a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Check the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) you finished before posting, especially [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: With 150k rep you'd think there'll be some code shown...

Comment: ouch. I think wim knows [ask]. This is different than a gimmethecode homework question...

Comment: You have 11,720 reputation from python answers. Surprised you couldn’t knock some code up, or that you didn’t know you should.

Comment: @Prune  I've edited the question to include an example attempt with MCVE.  I've already seen the intro tour some years ago, thank you!

Comment: @Prune tss tss canned comments for low reps, upvotes for high reps?

Comment: Did this output come from structlog?

Comment: @user2357112  https://github.com/hynek/structlog/blob/18.2.0/src/structlog/processors.py#L28

Comment: what the hell the guy was thinking when he built that format?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The key value renderer is intended for terminal output (human readable), not file logging.  In production, a json renderer to file or syslog would likely be configured instead.

Comment: meta effect gained us a downvote per answer (& also the question)...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes, it is unfortunate that the downvoter did not explain his reasoning.

Comment: because there _isn't_ any reasoning apart from high-rep bashing :) I'm saying that because our solutions are hackish but user2357112 solution is excellent & still got downvoted.

Comment: Likely not technical reasoning, just collateral damage. It's like even mentioning a question on meta earns a bomb of downvotes upon everyone in the vicinity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your input can't be conveniently parsed by something like `ast.literal_eval`, but it *can* be [tokenized](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html) as a series of Python tokens. This makes things a bit easier than they might otherwise be.

The only place `=` tokens can appear in your input is as key-value separators; at least for now, `ast.literal_eval` doesn't accept anything with `=` tokens in it. We can use the `=` tokens to determine where the key-value pairs start and end, and most of the rest of the work can be handled by `ast.literal_eval`. Using the `tokenize` module also avoids problems with `=` or backslash escapes in string literals.

```
import ast
import io
import tokenize

def todict(logstring):
    # tokenize.tokenize wants an argument that acts like the readline method of a binary
    # file-like object, so we have to do some work to give it that.
    input_as_file = io.BytesIO(logstring.encode('utf8'))
    tokens = list(tokenize.tokenize(input_as_file.readline))

    eqsign_locations = [i for i, token in enumerate(tokens) if token[1] == '=']

    names = [tokens[i-1][1] for i in eqsign_locations]

    # Values are harder than keys.
    val_starts = [i+1 for i in eqsign_locations]
    val_ends = [i-1 for i in eqsign_locations[1:]] + [len(tokens)]

    # tokenize.untokenize likes to add extra whitespace that ast.literal_eval
    # doesn't like. Removing the row/column information from the token records
    # seems to prevent extra leading whitespace, but the documentation doesn't
    # make enough promises for me to be comfortable with that, so we call
    # strip() as well.
    val_strings = [tokenize.untokenize(tok[:2] for tok in tokens[start:end]).strip()
                   for start, end in zip(val_starts, val_ends)]
    vals = [ast.literal_eval(val_string) for val_string in val_strings]

    return dict(zip(names, vals))
```

This behaves correctly on your example inputs, as well as on an example with backslashes:

```
>>> todict("key='hello world'")
{'key': 'hello world'}
>>> todict("k1='v1' k2='v2'")
{'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2'}
>>> todict("s='1234' n=1234")
{'s': '1234', 'n': 1234}
>>> todict("""k4='k5="hello"' k5={'k6': ['potato']}""")
{'k4': 'k5="hello"', 'k5': {'k6': ['potato']}}
>>> s=input()
a='=' b='"\'' c=3
>>> todict(s)
{'a': '=', 'b': '"\'', 'c': 3}
```

At the time this answer was written, looking for token type NAME instead of `=` tokens would also have been an option, but that'd break if they ever added `set()` support to `literal_eval`. As of Python 3.9, the devs *have* added `set()` support, so it looks like going for `=` tokens was a good move.

Comment: Re-using the tokenizer was a really creative and thinking-outside-the-box idea. Well done.

Answer (score 4):

*Regex replacement functions* to the rescue

I'm *not* rewriting a ast-like parser for you, but one trick that works pretty well is to use regular expressions to replace the quoted strings and replace them by "variables" (I've chosen `__token(number)__`), a bit like you're offuscating some code.

Make a note of the strings you're replacing (that should take care of the spaces), replace space by comma (protecting against symbols before like `:` allows to pass last test) and replace by strings again.

```
import re,itertools

def to_dict(s):
    rep_dict = {}
    cnt = itertools.count()
    def rep_func(m):
        rval = "__token{}__".format(next(cnt))
        rep_dict[rval] = m.group(0)
        return rval

    # replaces single/double quoted strings by token variable-like idents
    # going on a limb to support escaped quotes in the string and double escapes at the end of the string
    s = re.sub(r"(['\"]).*?([^\\]|\\\\)\1",rep_func,s)
    # replaces spaces that follow a letter/digit/underscore by comma
    s = re.sub("(\w)\s+",r"\1,",s)
    #print("debug",s)   # uncomment to see temp string
    # put back the original strings
    s = re.sub("__token\d+__",lambda m : rep_dict[m.group(0)],s)

    return eval("dict({s})".format(s=s))

print(to_dict("k1='v1' k2='v2'"))
print(to_dict("s='1234' n=1234"))
print(to_dict(r"key='hello world'"))
print(to_dict('key="hello world"'))
print(to_dict("""k4='k5="hello"' k5={'k6': ['potato']}"""))
# extreme string test
print(to_dict(r"key='hello \'world\\'"))
```

prints:

```
{'k2': 'v2', 'k1': 'v1'}
{'n': 1234, 's': '1234'}
{'key': 'hello world'}
{'key': 'hello world'}
{'k5': {'k6': ['potato']}, 'k4': 'k5="hello"'}
{'key': "hello 'world\\"}
```

The key is to extract the strings (quoted/double quoted) using non-greedy regex and replace them by non-strings (like if those were string *variables* not literals) in the expression. The regex has been tuned so it can accept escaped quotes and double escape at the end of string (custom solution)

The replacement function is an inner function so it can make use of the nonlocal dictionary & counter and track the replaced text, so it can be restored once the spaces have been taken care of.

When replacing the spaces by commas, you have to be careful not to do it after a colon (last test) or all things considered after a alphanum/underscore (hence the `\w` protection in the replacement regex for comma)

If we uncomment the debug print code just before the original strings are put back that prints:

```
debug k1=__token0__,k2=__token1__
debug s=__token0__,n=1234
debug key=__token0__
debug k4=__token0__,k5={__token1__: [__token2__]}
debug key=__token0__
```

The strings have been pwned, and the replacement of spaces has worked properly. With some more effort, it should probably be possible to quote the keys and replace `k1=` by `"k1":` so `ast.literal_eval` can be used instead of `eval` (more risky, and not required here)

I'm sure some super-complex expressions can break my code (I've even heard that there are very few json parsers able to parse 100% of the valid json files), but for the tests you submitted, it'll work (of course if some funny guy tries to put `__tokenxx__` idents in the original strings, that'll fail, maybe it could be replaced by some otherwise invalid-as-variable placeholders). I have built an Ada lexer using this technique some time ago to be able to avoid spaces in strings and that worked pretty well.

Answer (score 3):

You can find all the occurrences of `=` characters, and then find the maximum runs of characters which give a valid `ast.literal_eval` result. Those characters can then be parsed for the value, associated with a key found by a string slice between the last successful parse and the index of the current `=`:

```
import ast, typing
def is_valid(_str:str) -> bool:  
  try:
     _ = ast.literal_eval(_str)
  except:
    return False
  else:
    return True

def parse_line(_d:str) -> typing.Generator[typing.Tuple, None, None]:
  _eq, last = [i for i, a in enumerate(_d) if a == '='], 0
  for _loc in _eq:
     if _loc >= last:
       _key = _d[last:_loc]
       _inner, seen, _running, _worked = _loc+1, '', _loc+2, []
       while True:
         try:
            val = ast.literal_eval(_d[_inner:_running])
         except:
            _running += 1
         else:
            _max = max([i for i in range(len(_d[_inner:])) if is_valid(_d[_inner:_running+i])])
            yield (_key, ast.literal_eval(_d[_inner:_running+_max]))
            last = _running+_max
            break


def to_dict(_d:str) -> dict:
  return dict(parse_line(_d))
```

---

```
print([to_dict("key='hello world'"), 
       to_dict("k1='v1' k2='v2'"), 
       to_dict("s='1234' n=1234"), 
       to_dict("""k4='k5="hello"' k5={'k6': ['potato']}"""),
       to_dict("val=['100', 100, 300]"),
       to_dict("val=[{'t':{32:45}, 'stuff':100, 'extra':[]}, 100, 300]")
   ]

)
```

Output:

```
{'key': 'hello world'}
{'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2'}
{'s': '1234', 'n': 1234}
{'k4': 'k5="hello"', 'k5': {'k6': ['potato']}}
{'val': ['100', 100, 300]}
{'val': [{'t': {32: 45}, 'stuff': 100, 'extra': []}, 100, 300]}
```

Disclaimer:

This solution is not as elegant as @Jean-FrançoisFabre's, and I am not sure if it can parse 100% of what is passed to `to_dict`, but it may give you inspiration for your own version.

Comment: this solution chokes on escaped quotes (like mine BTW): try `"key='hello \'world'"`. It's near to impossible to write such a parser without really parsing the data

Answer (score 1):

#### Provide two helper functions.

- `popstr`: split thing from start of string that looks like string
  If it starts with a single or double quote mark, I'll look for the next one and split at that point.

  ```
  def popstr(s):
      i = s[1:].find(s[0]) + 2
      return s[:i], s[i:]
  ```
- `poptrt`: split thing from start of string that is surrounded by brackets ('[]', '()', '{}').
  If it starts with a bracket, I'll start incrementing for every instance of the starting character and decrementing for every  instance of it's complement.  When I reach zero, I split.

  def poptrt(s):
      d = {'{': '}', '[': ']', '(': ')'}
      b = s[0]
      c = lambda x: {b: 1, d[b]: -1}.get(x, 0)
      parts = []
      t, i = 1, 1
      while t > 0 and s:
          if i > len(s) - 1:
              break
          elif s[i] in '\'"':
              *s, s*, s = s[:i], *map(str.strip, popstr(s[i:]))
              parts.extend([*s, s*])
              i = 0
          else:
              t += c(s[i])
              i += 1
      if t == 0:
          return ''.join(parts + [s[:i]]), s[i:]
      else:
          raise ValueError('Your string has unbalanced brackets.')

---

#### Chew through string until there is no more string to chew

```
def to_dict(log):
    d = {}
    while log:
        k, log = map(str.strip, log.split('=', 1))
        if log.startswith(('"', "'")):
            v, log = map(str.strip, popstr(log))
        elif log.startswith((*'{[(',)):
            v, log = map(str.strip, poptrt(log))
        else:
            v, *log = map(str.strip, log.split(None, 1))
            log = ' '.join(log)
        d[k] = ast.literal_eval(v)
    return d
```

---

#### All tests passed

```
assert to_dict("key='hello world'") == {'key': 'hello world'}
assert to_dict("k1='v1' k2='v2'") == {'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2'}
assert to_dict("s='1234' n=1234") == {'s': '1234', 'n': 1234}
assert to_dict("""k4='k5="hello"' k5={'k6': ['potato']}""") == {'k4': 'k5="hello"', 'k5': {'k6': ['potato']}}
```

---

#### Deficiencies

- Did not account for backslashes
- Did not account for nested goofy formatting

---

#### All Together

```
import ast

def popstr(s):
    i = s[1:].find(s[0]) + 2
    return s[:i], s[i:]

def poptrt(s):
    d = {'{': '}', '[': ']', '(': ')'}
    b = s[0]
    c = lambda x: {b: 1, d[b]: -1}.get(x, 0)
    parts = []
    t, i = 1, 1
    while t > 0 and s:
        if i > len(s) - 1:
            break
        elif s[i] in '\'"':
            _s, s_, s = s[:i], *map(str.strip, popstr(s[i:]))
            parts.extend([_s, s_])
            i = 0
        else:
            t += c(s[i])
            i += 1
    if t == 0:
        return ''.join(parts + [s[:i]]), s[i:]
    else:
        raise ValueError('Your string has unbalanced brackets.')

def to_dict(log):
    d = {}
    while log:
        k, log = map(str.strip, log.split('=', 1))
        if log.startswith(('"', "'")):
            v, log = map(str.strip, popstr(log))
        elif log.startswith((*'{[(',)):
            v, log = map(str.strip, poptrt(log))
        else:
            v, *log = map(str.strip, log.split(None, 1))
            log = ' '.join(log)
        d[k] = ast.literal_eval(v)
    return d
```

Answer (score -2):

I have similar problem to convert `'key1="value1" key2="value2" ...'` string into dict. I split string on spaces and create a list of `['key="value"']` pairs. Than in cycle through list again, split pairs on '=' and add pairs to dict.

Code:

```py
str_attr = 'name="Attr1" type="Attr2" use="Attr3"'

list_attr = str_attr.split(' ')
dict_attr = {}
for item in list_attr:
    list_item = item.split('=')
    dict_attr.update({list_item[0] : list_item[1]})
    
print(dict_attr)
```

result:

```
{'name': '"Attr1"', 'type': '"Attr2"', 'use': '"Attr3"'}
```

Limitations:

- keys and values should don't have space (' ') and/or equal sign ('=') inside.

If you have different delimiters like spaces, commas, commas with spaces, semicolon et cetera, use regex to split string, specify delimiters by '|':

```
'\s+|,\s*|;\s*'
\s+ - one or more spaces
",\s*" - colon or colon with space(s)
";\s*" - semicolon or semicolon with space(s)
"+" means "one or more"
"*" means "none or more"
```

```py
import re

str_attr = 'name="Attr1"    type="Attr2",    use="Attr3",new="yes";old="no"'

list_attr = re.split(''\s+|,\s*|;\s*'', str_attr)
dict_attr = {}
for item in list_attr:
    if item:
        list_item = item.split('=')
        dict_attr.update({list_item[0] : list_item[1]})
    
print(dict_attr)
```

Result:

```
{'name': '"Attr1"', 'type': '"Attr2"', 'use': '"Attr3"', 'new': '"yes"', 'old': '"no"'}
```

Comment: "Limitations:" - the entire point of the question is that OP already tried a substantively similar approach, and ran into the same limitations, and required code that isn't limited in that way.