# Best way to read a text data file with key="value" format?

Tags: python, text

I have a text file formatted like:

```
item(1) description="Tofu" Group="Foods" Quantity=5
item(2) description="Apples" Group="Foods" Quantity=10
```

What's the best way to read this style of format in Python?

Comment: Was there a particular problem when you tried to read this file?

Comment: This is actually a surprisingly difficult problem.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/52898954/674039

Answer (score -1):

Here's one way you could do this in [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) to get a DataFrame of your items.

(I copy-pasted your text file into "test.txt" for testing purposes.)

This method automatically assigns column names and sets the `item(...)` column as the index. You could also assign the column names manually, which would change the script a bit.

```py
import pandas as pd

# read in the data
df = pd.read_csv("test.txt", delimiter=" ", header=None)

# set the index as the first column
df = df.set_index(0)

# capture our column names, to rename columns
column_names = []

# for each column...
for col in df.columns:
    # extract the column name
    col_name = df[col].str.split("=").str[0].unique()[0]
    column_names.append(col_name)

    # extract the data
    col_data = df[col].str.split("=").str[1]

    # optional: remove the double quotes
    try:
        col_data = col_data.replace('"', "")
    except:
        pass

    # store just the data back in the column
    df[col] = col_data

# store our new column names
df.columns = column_names
```

There are probably a lot of ways to do this based on what you're trying to accomplish and how much variation you expect in the data.

Comment: The main thing I'm running into is how to setup the column names based on the data, especially if Group and Quantity get swapped on different lines.

Comment: @ElliottVentura -- When you say "swapped", do you mean that the ordering of the items on the line will be different? In other words, sometimes the order is Description, then Group, then Quantity, and sometimes the order is Description, then Quantity, then Group? If that's the case, I can try to edit my solution to address that. That situation probably involves processing the lines one at a time.