# How to convert unquoted list of dictionaries to proper json format

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries that are coming out unquoted, such as below:

> '[{reason: NA, employeeName: bob smith}, {reason: NA, employeName: tom jones}]'

I need to have this converted to a proper json format to look like this:

> [{"reason": "NA", "employeeName:" "bob smith"}, {"reason": "NA", "employeName": "tom jones"}]

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Is the input coming as a string ?

Comment: How'd you get those unquoted dicts in the first place…?

Comment: Yes it is coming in as a string. This is just the input I received, can't modify that

Comment: How do you know that the proper interpretation isn't `[{"reason": "NA, employeeName: bob smith"}, {"reason": "NA, employeName: tom jones"}]`?  There is a REASON why we need a delimiter around strings, you *cannot* reliably reconstruct the data without them.

Comment: `json.dumps` will do the job for you

Comment: @Exciter How'll it do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [regexp](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp) for that. On [this site](https://regexr.com/6j458), you can test and learn how to use them.

So here is how I would solve your problem :

```
import json
import re

l = '[{reason: NA, employeeName: bob smith}, {reason: NA, employeName: tom jones, createdAt: 2021-04-28 17:04:52.684064+00:00}]'
res = []
objects = re.findall(r'{[^}]*}', l)
for o in objects:
    attr = re.findall(r'([^:,{]*):([^,}]*)', o)
    res.append({}) 
    for a in attr:
        res[-1][a[0].strip()] = a[1].strip()
print(json.dumps(res))
```

Comment: So this works for the most part, except I have some fields that are a date timestamp:

createdAt: 2021-04-28 17:04:52.684064+00:00

Turns into

"createdAt": "2021", "27 14": "44", "": "08", "00": "00"

Any workaround for that? @Dj0ulo

Comment: No problem I edited the second regexp !

Answer (score 1):

For the idea behind it, we took this list , and dealt with each dictionary alone , we turned it to a string so we can manipulate it.
Next we're recreating the dictionary, by defining the key and the item foe each step:
so as an example:

```
list_dict1 = '[{reason: NA, employeeName: bob smith}, {reason: NA, employeName: tom jones}]'
result=[]
# Converting string to list
list_dict2 = list_dict1.strip('][').split(', ')
# => it converts string representation of list to a list
for i in list_dict2:
# we loop on each inner "dictionary" rep
   s=str(i)# so we can use strip and split methods 
   d = dict([
    (x.split(':')[0].strip(), x.split(':')[1].strip("' "))
    for x in s.strip("{}").split(',')
   ])
   # for each x that represents key:item, cs we deleted {} and we split 
   them based on ","
   # Next we defined the key as being the first item , if we split using 
   # ":", and so on
   result.append(d)
   # we're appending each new dictionary created to our result list
result
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37935918/how-to-turn-a-string-with-unquoted-keys-into-a-dict-in-python

Comment: The input is coming in as a string so this won't work against that.

Comment: That question had the values quoted, so this is a different input

Answer (score -1):

Here is my small Python Example with the `json` lib.

```py
import json

data=[{"reason": "NA", "employeeName:" "bob smith"}, {"reason": "NA", "employeName": "tom jones"}]

json.dumps(data)
# output:
#'[{"reason": "NA", "employeeName:": "bob smith"}, {"reason": "NA", "employeName": "tom jones"}]'
```